# laravel with docker nginx php slow response time ttfb 120 seconds

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-run

i have a container with php and nginx and a laravel project. it works on production fine. but on my develop environment (kubuntu 21.04) is work slow. every time i send a request (its static and very simple), it takes exactly 2 minutes. (ttfb = 2min).
i run it with this command.

```
docker run -it --volume=$PWD:/app -w=/app  -p8000:8000 registry.gitlab.com/myImages/php-nginx:myLaravelApp php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

ps: if i put a file url like a json or png address bar from my laravel project, its OK and run very fast.

this method works on my co workers even with windows environmet.